# How do I insert a title slide into a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I created a presentation without a title.  Now I need a title slide.  How do I insert a slide and then indicate to PowerPoint that its master slide should be the title master?

EDIT: Am running 2016 on a Mac.

Comment: The master slide is the slide that contains the basic formatting/colors/styles that all other slides will base their design from. The master slide is never shown when presenting. The title slide is just the slide at the beginning of the slide show that has your title message on it. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a new slide, then change its layout to Title Slide.  Since you haven't indicated which version of PowerPoint you use or on what platform, it's difficult to give specific step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Running 2013 on a Mac.  Edited my question.

Comment: Care to edit again?  There's no 2013 for Mac.  2011 or 2016, unless your version's quite old.

Comment: Well, thought I had it figured out.  I think it must be 2016.

Comment: On the INSERT or HOME tabs, click the downward-pointing triangle next to NEW SLIDE and in the gallery that appears, choose TITLE SLIDE.  If you've already inserted a slide and want to change it to a title layout, on the HOME tab, click the uppermost icon to the right of NEW SLIDE and choose the title slide layout from the gallery that appears.  And by the way, you can learn the version specifics by clicking PowerPoint at the left of the main menu, then clicking About PowerPoint.  Same is true of pretty much any Mac app.